# Why my network connection profile doesnt contain the MAC address?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, mac

I'm writing a script that is supposed to see all the mac address of the previously connected networks so I googled and saw that
`cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mywifi.nmconnection`
is suppposed to print all info related to this network including the router MAC address, but it seems that only the available fields are

```
[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=84;80;45;76;73;78;
```

with no reference to MAC address anywhere in the file. I'm running Ubuntu `20.04 LTS` with kernel version `5.4.0`. So where are all the mac address of all previously connected to networks are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got the idea that Network Manager is "supposed to" have the MAC address of the WiFi base station that the computer is connecting to in the `.nmconnection` file, but you can certainly *specify* a MAC address in that file if you want to reduce the risk of falling prey to SSID spoofing.

Network Manager will, however, record the MAC address of the WiFi base station in `/var/log/syslog`. This is what one record looks like from my `syslog` file:

```
Jan 19 13:09:11 Carbon wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp4s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with a4:12:42:e7:f6:66 [GTK=CCMP]
```

This is not particularly useful, given the amount of "noise" that you would have to parse, as `syslog` can get quite busy. That said, you can build a mechanism yourself if you're so inclined. Here is a one-liner that will give you the MAC address of the WiFi base station you are connected to:

```
ip neigh|grep "$(ip -4 route list 0/0|head -1|cut -d' ' -f3) "|cut -d' ' -f5|tr '[a-f]' '[A-F]'
```

For me, this returns:

```
A4:12:42:E7:F6:64
```

***NOTE:** If you are connected to both wired and wireless networks when running this command, you will receive multiple addresses.*

This can be put into a regular monitoring script where the data is recorded to any place that you'd like in whatever format you would like. This should make it much easier for you to organise and use the information you're looking for.

While this isn't exactly an answer to your question, I hope it gives you something to consider.

Comment: it was actually several sites that stated that including one in this site, also I have this site https://www.idiotinside.com/2015/02/16/how-to-find-saved-wifi-password-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/. Look at the images you will see the mac address.

Comment: Yes, I can see examples with a MAC address. As outlined in the very first paragraph of the answer, you can *specify* an IP address. That does not mean that Network Manager is "supposed to" have it there. Either way, with the `ip neigh` command, you can create more verbose records of device MAC addresses to suit your specific requirements 

Comment: but do you know any way so that I get the address of previously connected to networks since the above method will return only the address of currently connected network ?.

Comment: For an *incomplete* list, you will need to write something that will read through your various `syslog` files that exist in `/var/log/`. This includes the `.gz` archives, which get rotated into oblivion as time passes. `grep` might help you with something like `sudo grep 'WPA: Key negotiation completed' /var/log/syslog`, but this would still be an incomplete solution. If this is something you want to track long term, you'll need to start logging it in a useful manner.